# Adding words from a text file to a list (python 2.7)

Tags: python, text, lines

Assuming I have a text file.
My goal is to write a function which receives a number of line to go over in the text file and returns a list, each cell in the list containing one word exactly from that line.
Any idea of how doing this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with small files:

```
def get_words(mifile, my_line_number):
    with open(mifile) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        myline = lines[my_line_number]    #first line is 0
        return myline.split()
```

you get all the file lines in the list `lines`. This is not very efficient for VERY big files. In that case probably it would be better to iterate line by line until you arrive to the chosen line.

Answer (score 1):

Given the `filename` and the line number (`lineno`), you could extract the words on that line this way:

Assuming the `lineno` is not too large:

```
import linecache

line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno)
words = line.split()
```

Or, if the `lineno` is large:

```
import itertools

with open(filename,'r') as f:        
    line = next(itertools.islice(f,lineno-1,None))
    words = line.split()
```

This,of course,assumes that words are separated by spaces--which may not be the case in hard-to-parse text.

Comment: +1 for linecache, ops sorry, daily vote reached. have to wait 8 hours :-)